# How to detect the state of a toggle button on a ribbon?

Tags: c#, vsto, ribbon, togglebutton

I've added a toggle button to my ribbon and now, I'd like to send its state to an other object. The code is below.

```
public void Butt_Click(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
  something.SendButtVal(control.State);
}
```

Of course, `control.State` doesn't work. I suspect that I'll need to cast `control` to type `ToggleButton` or something like that but intellisense gives me nothing...

I can see that the API for the interface `IRibbonControl` is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.core.iribboncontrol_members.aspx) but I'd like to see a list of implementing classes, like in JavaDocs. How do I get there?

EDIT

Please note that I'm asking about a ribbon component. See the method signature. It's a toggle button on a ribbon. The problem is that I don't get `Checked` property and (probably) need to cast `control` to correct type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to alter your signature. It's not correct for a toggle button. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa433867%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for details.

```
public void ToggleButtonOnAction(IRibbonControl control, bool pressed)
{
  MessageBox.Show("ToggleButton was switched " + pressed ? "on" : "off");
}
```

Comment: I think it worked like that in Office 2007 but I'm on Office 2010 and the method with `bool` parameter isn't called. There's an article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862101.aspx) saying that it should be but it isn't!

Comment: It's there, make sure in your ribbon XML that your button is defined as <toggleButton /> not <button />